# Ctrl + Alt + Delete shortcut (Loki)

Tags: release-loki, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For a while I've been trying to make Ctrl + Alt + Delete open Gnome System Monitor but it won't work in Loki. If I change it to ctrl + super + delete it works but that is not what I want.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a collision of keyboard shortcuts in default Loki. In gsettings, the `logout` key under `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys` has the default value `<Control><Alt>Delete`.

1. So after you have set this key to empty (or anything else you want to):

   ```
   $  gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys logout ''
   ```
2. You can add a custom shortcut to trigger `gnome-system-monitor` with this key combination:
   [image]